# Flutter validation in another class steps

Tags: flutter, dart, stepper

I have created three pages and i putting them in a stepper, it means three pages in three different class in one stepper
The question is how i can add validation for a filed and check validate by pressing onContinue in stepper

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is a bit unclear, so it'll be difficult for others to help you. Try making your question more specific and include what you tried

Comment: Can i validation a fild in another class ?

Comment: Try this https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation